# Huawei P30 Pro I can't set sleep mode to never

Tags: battery, screen, clock, sleep

I just got my new Huawei P30 Pro and I am not able to set sleep mode to never. Maximum option available is 10 minutes. My battery mode is correct and it is set to "highest performance" so without any battery saving. I want to see my timer whole the time counting 1h and I am not able to do such an easy thing what is extremely annoying. I tried Automate or Caffeine apps but they don't work for me. My EMUI version is 10.

Please for help.

Comment: The Huawei P30 Pro has an OLED display. OLED displays have problems if the screen shows the same content for a long time in such a case it will suffer from burn-in effects. I would assume that therefore you can only have a maximum on-time before sleep of 10 minutes. The only chance I see is that in the debug menu there is sometimes an entry to keep the device awake when it is connected via USB. However activating it may severely damage your display on a long term (at least reduce the brightness when using it)!

Comment: That's ridiculous. I feel like I downgraded from my Xiaomi MI5...